# Visual Studio Code Debug Console colours

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am using Light (Visual Studio) theme. The yellow text on the debug console is just not visible. How to change it? https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color doesn't have the info! Who the hell on earth would use Yellow text On White background colour!?!

Comment: Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735278/modify-editor-text-color-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: That's for editor. Not debug console.

Comment: Check this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47457

Comment: I believe that the yellow is not supported color..

Comment: That issue was using *Dark* theme. Use Light Theme and check the debug console.

Answer (score 14):

Adding the following after the "`workbench.colorTheme`" option worked for me in 14.9.2.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "debugConsole.warningForeground": "#800",
    "debugConsole.errorForeground": "#d00",
    "debugConsole.sourceForeground": "#0c0",
    "debugConsole.infoForeground": "#00f"
}
```