# VSCode + Debugger console. How to change the color of text in debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

Light theme color is not visible in the debugger.

[image: Screen debug console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this lines after the "*workbench.colorTheme*" option.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "debugConsole.warningForeground": "#HEXCODE",
    "debugConsole.errorForeground": "#HEXCODE",
    "debugConsole.sourceForeground": "#HEXCODE",
    "debugConsole.infoForeground": "#HEXCODE"
}
```

You also have some information here:
[Modify editor text color in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735278/modify-editor-text-color-in-visual-studio-code)